# Updating salesforce records using RStudio - How to update multiple records from data frame?

Tags: r, salesforce

I'm attempting to update a list of Salesforce records using Rforcecom.

If I use this code to update one record, it works perfectly:

```
objectName <- "Opportunity"
id <- "0060W00000wzkmH" #actual record ID of one specific record in salesforce
fields <- c(PatronDonate__Acknowledged__c="true")
rforcecom.update(session, objectName, id, fields)
```

But when I try to iterate through the data frame to update multiple records, it throws this error:

```
length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I've tried a few different ways of accomplishing this without luck, and they all work if I substitute a specific salesforce record ID for the dataframe identifier that I need to provide in order for the code to iterate. For example, this doesn't work:

```
nrowsdf <- nrow(dataframe)
for(i in 1:nrowsdf) {  
  objectName <- "Opportunity"
  id <- dataframe$Record.ID
  fields <- c(PatronDonate__Acknowledged__c="true")
  rforcecom.update(session, objectName, id, fields)
}
```

But this does work (it updates one specific record, but obviously it won't update a list of records):

```
nrowsdf <- nrow(dataframe)
for(i in 1:nrowsdf) {  
    objectName <- "Opportunity"
    id <- "0060W00000wzkmH"
    fields <- c(PatronDonate__Acknowledged__c="true")
    rforcecom.update(session, objectName, id, fields)
}
```

Any help hugely appreciated. I haven't worked with Rforcecom or salesforce before.

Comment: It seems clear that you are sending a vector with a length greater than 1. I don't know enough about the Salesforce API but you should realize that "true" is not a logical vector in R. It's just another character value.

Comment: I found a way to get it to work by specifying the row (dataframe$Record.ID[newrow]), where "newrow" is a variable that increases by 1 each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get it to work by specifying the row for each iteration through the loop:

```
inc <- function(x)
{
  eval.parent(substitute(x <- x + 1))
}

setrow <- 0

upsert <- function(x) {
  nrowsdf <- nrow(Records)
  for(i in 1:nrowsdf) {  
    newrow <- inc(setrow)
    fields <- c(PatronDonate__Acknowledged__c="1")
    rforcecom.update(session, "Opportunity", dataframe$Record.ID[newrow], fields)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**salesforcer**](https://github.com/StevenMMortimer/salesforcer) package can update records using the REST, SOAP, or Bulk APIs by operating directly on data.frames so no looping is necessary. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(salesforcer)
sf_auth(username, password, security_token)

n <- 2
new_contacts <- tibble(FirstName = rep("Test", n),
                       LastName = paste0("Contact-Create-", 1:n))
created_records <- sf_create(new_contacts, "Contact")
created_records
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   id                 success
#>   <chr>              <lgl>  
#> 1 0033s00000zN3JvAAK TRUE   
#> 2 0033s00000zN3JwAAK TRUE

updated_contacts <- created_records %>%
    select(id) %>%
    mutate(FirstName = "TestTest")
updated_records <- sf_update(updated_contacts, "Contact")
updated_records
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   id                 success
#>   <chr>              <lgl>  
#> 1 0033s00000zN3JvAAK TRUE   
#> 2 0033s00000zN3JwAAK TRUE

# confirm update by querying the fields of these two records
my_soql <- sprintf("SELECT Id, 
                           FirstName, 
                           LastName
                   FROM Contact 
                   WHERE Id in ('%s')", 
                   paste0(created_records$id , collapse="','"))
queried_records <- sf_query(my_soql)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Id                 FirstName LastName        
#>   <chr>              <chr>     <chr>           
#> 1 0033s00000zN3JvAAK TestTest  Contact-Create-1
#> 2 0033s00000zN3JwAAK TestTest  Contact-Create-2
```